# What's the difference between request.env['REQUEST_URI'] and request.env['REQUEST_PATH']?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the difference between request.env['REQUEST_URI'] and request.env['REQUEST_PATH'] in Rails? They always seem to contain the same value.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I believe delroth is correct about the distinction, however in almost all cases it's better to use the methods in Request instead of directly accessing the environment variables.

**request.request_uri** returns the requested url including the query string and without the domain.

**request.path** returns the path of the request without the query string, domain and any relative root (if your app runs from a directory other than root).

See the Rails API for [ActionDispatch::Request](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html) to see other helpful methods.

Comment: request_uri is no longer a method in Rails 3.

Comment: In Rails 5 and 6, you can use `request.original_fullpath`

Answer (score 11):

I believe `REQUEST_URI` also contains query GET arguments, whereas `REQUEST_PATH` don't. But I'm not completely sure of that.

For example :

- `REQUEST_URI = /foo/bar/?x=1&y=2`
- `REQUEST_PATH = /foo/bar/`